# GetElementById().click not working in velocity template

Tags: javascript, click, velocity

I've javascript function that displays a confirm window; if ok it's clicked I want it to run a javascript function called into a button. Everything is inside a velocity template. Here it's the code:

```
    function alertAssociataAcl()
            {
              var deleteAceObj = document.getElementById("deleteAce");
              console.log(deleteAceObj);
              if (deleteAceObj) {
                 if (confirm("Text")){
                   deleteAceObj.value = "true";
                   var save=document.getElementById("salvautente");
                   save.click();
                   } 
              else{
                  deleteAceObj.value = "false";
                   }
               }
             }


        <td>
          #if ( $creazioneutenteperaoo == 'true' ) 

           <input id="salvautente" type="button" value="Salva" 
            onclick="selectedRuoliUfficiPerAmmAoo('$formUtente.oldCmd');">
         #else
           <input id="salvautente" type="button" value="Salva" 
            onclick="selectedRuoliUffici('$formUtente.oldCmd');">                               
         #end
         #if($formUtente.errorMessage.equals("String"))
           <script>
            alertAssociataAcl();
           </script>
         #end
      </td>
```

When I press ok in the confirm window the function doesn't click on the save button. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you post us the generated file (the html source from the browser)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to trigger a `click`, you just need to call the function:

```
if (confirm("Text")){
  deleteAceObj.value = "true";
  selectedRuoliUfficiPerAmmAoo('$formUtente.oldCmd');
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, I tried but It doesn't work. I think it's because '$formUtente.oldCmd') is a velocity Parameter....